# Indexing array/subobject in mongoDB causes duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection where I will have a `_children` attribute like this:

```
{
  _children: {
    videoTags: [ { id: '1', name: 'one'}, { id: '2', name: 'two'} ],
  },
  a: 10
}
```

Since I WILL search in videoTags, I create an index as such:

```
> db.test4.createIndex({ "_children.videosTags.id" : 1 }, { "unique" : true } );
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Trouble is, I can no longer add *anything* to that table since I get a duplicate index error. Here is how to reproduce it:

- Step 1: insert to a collection

`db.test4.insert({a:20})
    WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })`

- Step 2: make the index

`db.test4.createIndex({ "_children.videosTags.id" : 1 }, { "unique" : true } );
    {
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
    }`

- Step 3: try to insert again

`db.test4.insert({a:30})
    WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: wonder_1.test4.$_children.videosTags.id_1  dup key: { : null }"
        }
    })`

I think the issue here is that there is *already* a record where _children.videoTags.id is not defined.

However, what I expected was a behaviour where *if* videoTags.id was specified, it needed to be unique. Instead, an empty one is considered a "taken" key.

What am I doing that is stupidly wrong?
This will work if you don't set `unique` as `true`, but I have the feeling I need to fix it for real...

Comment: This will be because another document already has an empty array ( or at least an element without an `"id"` field. You can either use `"sparse"`, or ensure that all array elements have an `"id"` field. Placing a `"unique"` index that you know is going to be on an array element ( even if you really intend a unique id collection wide ) can be fraught with problems. It's generally not advised.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- that was exactly it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two reasons.

1. There could be other documents exists in collection with same `_children.videosTags.id`
2. It's quite possible that more than one document may have missing  `_children.videosTags.id"` or having null value.

As you are creating `unique` key, null or empty values are give you tough time. Solution is either create `sparse` index and if your MongoDB version is 3.2+, create partial index. See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-indexes) for partial indexes.